# Mongoose, is it possible to assign parent id to sub document on save in one call?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am wondering if it's possible(or even needed) to provide a subdocument with a reference to it's parents id all in one call. Here is the code I'm working with:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var LatLng = new Schema({
  id: Schema.ObjectId,
  created_at: Date,
  accuracy: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  latitude: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  longitude: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  _walk: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Walk',
    required: true
  }
});
LatLng.pre('save', function(next){
  if(!this.created_at)
    this.created_at = new Date();
});

var Walk = new Schema({
  id: Schema.ObjectId,
  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date,
  description: String,
  elapsedTime: Number,
  distance: Number,
  waypoints: [LatLng],
  _user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
  }
});

Walk.pre('save', function(next){
  var now = new Date();
  this.updated_at = now;
  if(!this.created_at)
    this.created_at = now;
  next();
});

Walk.pre('update', function(next){
  this.updated_at = new Date();
});

Walk.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function(next){
  this.updated_at = new Date();
});

Walk.pre('findByIdAndUpdate', function(next){
  this.updated_at = new Date();
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Walk', Walk);
```

Wondering if there's some way, maybe in `LatLng.pre('save')`, to assign `LatLng._walk` to `Walk.id`?

So when I do something like:

```
var walk = new Walk({
    description: req.body.description,
    elapsedTime: req.body.elapsedTime,
    distance: req.body.distance,
    waypoints: req.body.waypoints,
    _user: req.user._id
  });
```

It would allow me to just call `walk.save()` and not have to iterate through the `waypoints` and manually assign `_walk` to `walk._id`

I hope this makes sense, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you really do need it why not just manually create it before and save the document with it. You can generate the ObjectId yourself instead of letting mongo handle it. There is nothing against that.

Comment: Honestly I have no idea if I need it, I'm just assuming I do. But if I do your saying I can manually create it in the pre save method?

Comment: Do you save all of your Objects at the same time. like you Create a Walk object then create a bunch of LatLng objects and save them all?

Comment: Sorry I'm pretty new to all of this still, but I would like to just setup my model to simply be able to pass a JSON string like `var walk = new Walk(json);` and just call it's save function...

Comment: Honestly your best bet is your probably don't need it. If you are storing them as sub documents then you always know from which parent document it came from. The only reason you would need to store the parent ID is if you were storing them in a separate collection.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but wasn't too sure. I think I'll go with that, should make it a lot easier to deal with, thanks.